# Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, sockets, server, serversocket

I am trying to connect using socket_connect using PHP script but I am getting the error

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Below is my script I am trying:

```
     <?php
     $host    = "127.0.0.1";

    $port    = 51007;
    $message = "Hello Server";
   echo "Message To server :".$message;
   // create socket

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    // connect to server
   $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
   // send string to server
   socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
  // get server response
  $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
   echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
   // close socket
   socket_close($socket);

?>
```

When I tried first time it shows me correct output from server but when I reload browser It displaying error as I mentioned in subject. I am using Wampp in Windows 10.

I have also attached screen shot of my error, is there anything with configuration or in wrong?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to connect to exactly? Have you checked that the port is open and there is a service running on that port?

Comment: The server is not listening; you probably did not run that script, or let it die.